# Include code in html file in captcha context

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've a file that needs to have a php include

```
<? include_once("script.php") ?>
```

Javascript content

```
<script>
    Some javascript code
</script>
```

And HTML content:

```
<some tags>
```

So that I just have to do `code to include` in html and everything works as I need in the captcha.

I've tried `<link>, <iframe seamless> and <script>` but none worked... I need this piece of code to interact with the parent code, just like a regular include... How could I do this?

Comment: what is the extension of the original file? `.php` or `.html`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It just has to fit my conditions here. Can be anything.

Comment: So what exactly is _your condition_? this file which you are talking about, what is this file? is a `php` or `html` or what? if you are asking what type of file can handle all these three conditions which you've mentioned, a `php` file can do it easily. if not, please elaborate on you conditions.

Comment: Ok then. A PHP. I explicitly told I don't care for the file extension I just want to do the include. Would `<? include("script.php"); ?>` in the middle of the code work NP?

Comment: @EhsanT or is there any better extension / command?

Comment: that's the best way to insert the content of one `PHP` file into another `PHP`